# Optimize Roles authorization in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, owin

I am making an asp.NET MVC5 intranet website for my company and as I have just finished implementing authorization and a dynamic menu according to user roles in Active Directory, I need to apply restrictions for access. I have read on MSDN / Technet that you can apply authorizations by using `[Authorize(Role="<YourRole>")]` and I make it work perfectly. Now my problem is that I have a 20 differents roles, and each Role is linked with `Documents` and `Categories` in my MSSQL Database. This means that if you want  to access a document or a ressource, you must first find the corresponding entry in the DB (If you need I can explain this further). So If I implement Authorizations with the `[Authorize]` attribute, I will have to check my DB to see if the row exists, and if does I add it. I have started to do that with a static class :

```
public static class CustomRoles
{
    public const string Role1 = "Role1";
    public const string Role2 = "Role2";
    //And so on ...
}
```

Then in my controller action methods:

```
[Authorize(Roles=CustomRoles.Role1+","+CustomRoles.Role2)]
public ActionResult Index(){}
```

You can imagine doing this for each role will be long and tedious.

**So my question :** do you know of any better / simpler way to do this? Because I have to manually check each document (thousands!) and look then in another table what profiles are associated, and then apply the corresponding authorization. And technically, my dynamic menu is supposed to take care of this since you cannot see what is not available to you, but then again, using the URL you can access anything in this way if authorizations aren't implemented

**And also :** Not all roles are registered in my DB, most users have around 140 roles, but there are likely just 1 or 2 that are registered in the database. Is this going to create some performance issues? I know I can handle this when I create my `Claims` and filter out the ones not belonging to the DB but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: I did not understand what exactly you want, but I think I got your problem. You need a custom authorize attribute. Please check this post http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/07/24/writing-your-own-custom-aspnet-mvc-authorize-attributes it teaches how to write a custom one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround you could do is by using overidden `OnActionExecuting` method in the  `ActionFilter` instead of decorators `AuthorizeAttribute` to check if a user is authorized to do certain action or not.

Yep, you still need to *carefully* check of your role authorization, but *not sparsely*, as you only need to check *all* of them in *one* place, namely your action filter (or, to be more precise, your *single* `switch`). Also, putting everything in one place enable you to avoid redundancy and make the logic more compact whenever possible.

Example:

The `ActionFilter`:

```
public class AuthorizeActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {

        IPrincipal user = HttpContext.Current.User; //get the current user

        //Get controller name and action
        string controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

        //All roles will be defined here!
        List<string> rolesAccepted = new List<string>();
        switch (controllerName){
            case "Controller1": //suppose these three happen to have the same rules
            case "Controller2":
            case "Controller3":
                //Describe roles accepted for certain controller and action
                rolesAccepted = new List<string> { "Role1", "Role2" };            
                break;
            case "Controller4": //suppose these have specific restrictions only for some actions
                if (actionName == "action1") {//can also use switch 
                    rolesAccepted = new List<string> { "Role3", "Role4" };
                } else {
                    rolesAccepted = new List<string> { "Role5", "Role6", "Role7" };
                }
                break;
            ....
        }

        //Redirect to login if non of the user role is authorized
        if (!rolesAccepted.Any(x => user.IsInRole(x)){
            filterContext.Result = redirectToLogin();
            return;
        }
    }

    private ActionResult redirectToLogin() {
      return new RedirectToRouteResult(
          new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" })
        );
    }

}
```

Then you only need to put the `AuthorizeActionFilterAttribute` in every controller (and not roles in every single action) as you have handled all authorization in the single place:

```
[AuthorizeActionFilter]
public class Controller1 : Controller {
    ...
}

[AuthorizeActionFilter]
public class Controller2 : Controller {
    ...
}

... and so on
```

Comment: Ah nice! This is what I was looking for, I will test it and mark as answer once I make it work, thanks!

Comment: @LéonardLaiter you are welcome. Please check it out!

Comment: Glad to know that!